# Android application and time-consuming native code

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface

I am working on an image processing Android application. Suppose you have a C++ singleton object that provides some time-consuming functions and allocates its own memory. Furhtermore, the C++ library will provide some other functions that will do some time-consuming work as well. This functions will be called by the singleton object. They can allocate their own temporary memory (that will be freed on function termination) and need to exchange data with the singleton object. The workflow is the following:

1. the native C++ library is loaded, the singleton object created (it will allocate memory and load data from the asset directory).
2. the user, using the application interface, select an image and loads it
3. the image is passed to the singleton object that will computes some informations
4. the user can request a particular image processing algorithm, the singleton object is    asked to call the corresponing function
5. repeat from 4 or go to 2 if the user load another image (the singleton object will be    resetted (the memory allocated on step 1 is retained until the application is tereminated)).

Step 2 and 3 are the most time consuming part of the app. I would like the user to be able to stop the current processing if too much time is passed and the application to remain responsive during the time consuming processing algorithms. The most simple way to do this app is to call the native functions and wait the, but this will probably block the UI. Another way is to design those functions to check a flag every N processed pixels to know if the function must stop (this would allow me to free memory when it happens). A third option could be to use java threads, but how?

Comment: All process intesive taks need to be performed on a separate thread. You have three options for this: AsyncTask, Thread, Loader.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to run the time consuming task off the UI thread.  You could do this with a native thread, but it would be simpler to call the native function from a background thread in java - there are several ways you can do that, such as an async task, etc which you can read about.

When you start the time consuming operation, you'll want the UI to display some sort of busy indicator to the user.  The UI thread will have to remain responsive (ie, the user can 'back' or 'home') but you can disable most of your other controls if you wish.

Your native operation in the background thread would, as you suggested, periodically check a stop request flag.  You will probably find it easiest to make that a native flag and set it with another (brief) native function called from the UI thread; there's the option of making it a java flag and calling java from C to check it, but that seems more complicated.

If your processing is going to be especially lengthy, arguably you should do the work not only in the background, but in the context of an Android service rather than that of an activity.  To a first approximation, native code will not care about the difference, however there are potential implications for what happens if the activity goes to the background during processing - if the work is being done in a service (or more specifically, if the process contains a service which is active), Android will try to let it keep running if possible.  In contrast, if the process only has an activity which is now not active because something else is in the foreground, Android is more likely to kill it or throttle its available CPU.  Ultimately, whatever you do your native code will need to deal with the possibility of its process being killed before the work is done - ie, you have to be able to recover from such a state when a new process is created as the user returns your activity to the foreground.  Having your flag also able to notify the native code of an onDestroy() call as an alert to save its work could be a help, but it will still need to be able to recover (at least cleanly re-do) from being killed without the courtesy of that notification.

Comment: I have a question. You say that the app should be able "to recover from such a state when a new process is created as the user returns your activity to the foreground". This confuses me because i thought that the application process ends only after onDestroy() is called. This passage confuses me as well: "but it will still need to be able to recover (at least cleanly re-do) from being killed without the courtesy of that notification". The onDestroy() method is called every time the application is killed, right?

Comment: From the documentation, i see that onPause() could be the last method called of the activity.

Comment: No, Android is also allowed to kill the process with no warning whatsoever.  This isn't extremely common, so having to re-do computation as a result would be okay, but it does happen, so you need to insure that it doesn't leave you in a corrupt state from which automatic, user-invisible recovery is not possible.  Also, you may not want onPause() to stop your processing.